# Equivalent SDP problems different solving times

Tags: semidefinite-programming, complexity

I have two SDP problems which are proved to be equivalent (in terms of optimal objective values) to each other in theory. Moreover, they have same number of constraints and variables respectively.  But in numerical tests, we found out that solving one is faster than the other. I can't find a reason to explain this observation.  Do you have any idea about the possible reasons to explain this?

Comment: My knowledge of SDP is minimal, but in exact linear algebra, precise analysis reveals that solving linear systems is sensitive to the matrix being "well-conditioned" (e.g. inverse of an integer matrix whose rational entries have a much larger denominator than numerator).